# What local IP should i use for port forwarding?

Tags: port-forwarding

I use nordVPN to port forward, because my ISP blocking the ports, so when I installed the VPN it shows 2 networks on my computer, so what local IP should i use on my router port forwarding configuration?

[image: Screenshot of output of ipconfig showing two adaptors with UP address and a few without]

Comment: Im not sure your question makes sense. What VPN software do you use, and does the VPN terminate on your pc or router?

Comment: I use nordvpn on my PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a VPN supports port-forwarding depends on the VPN server and whether
a tool is available for entering the needed parameters.

See the Redit article
[List of VPNs that allow P2P and Port Forwarding](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPNTorrents/comments/3oar5m/list_of_vpns_that_allow_p2p_and_port_forwarding/)
for choosing a better VPN provider.

Enabling VPN port-forwarding is usually done in the user area of the VPN’s
web interface, but is sometimes done in the VPN client software.
Some VPN services only allow port forwarding on specified servers.

For example, here are forwarded ports on the AirVPN interface:

[image]

For more information, see
[The Ultimate Guide to VPN Port Forwarding](https://www.bestvpn.com/guides/vpn-port-forwarding-guide/).

If the issue you have is INBOUND access and not outbound,
and if you control the port, then note that
your ISP cannot possibly have closed all ports, otherwise the connection
would be pointless. However, they will have restricted them.
As long as you have access to port 443 (the default for HTTPS),
there are VPN services you can use.

Another solution would be to find a VPS (Virtual Private Server) provider
that allows private VPN use (many don't) and set up OpenVPN on it, thus
having your own VPN server.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are neither will work the way you want it to. A quick look suggests that both IP addresses are [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) addresses, and you're behind a NAT in both cases. The point of port forwarding is to connect a single port from a public IP address to a NAT, and you have no control in either case.

So... You can't forward a port from the VPN unless you control the other VPN endpoint and can forward the port there - which pretty much isn't what most "privacy" centric VPNs are designed for. You can't forward a port from the router cause the port is blocked. More or less, neither IP will work.

In either case you're out of luck.

Comment: It should work. Because the VPN packet is fully encrypted to the VPN device, which in turn decrypts and determines where to send (in this case, based on port forwarding). The port number contained in the packet the ISP sees is encrypted. To the ISP, only the packet header to the VPN is in cleartext. Unless there are other deep packet inspection tells based on protocol/packet behavior, the ISP shouldn't be able determine the kind of traffic and block.

Comment: You don't control the other end - so you can't actually forward the port. Now if this was a VPN out to a server you controlled, this would be a different story altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [NordVPN FAQ](https://nordvpn.com/faq/):

> ## Do you offer any open ports?
>
> All ports are open on our servers, except SMTP and Netbios for outgoing connections. For the SMTP incoming port, you can alternatively use ports 465 or 587. **Of course, since we do not provide any port-forwarding, no incoming connections can go through.**

(Emphasis mine)

This means that NordVPN will not help you bypass any restrictions your ISP may impose on incoming connections. This is also true for most VPN services, because the required infrastructure is basically impossible to obtain with IPv4 addresses running out.

The easiest way is to just rent a VPS (at DigitalOcean or whatever) and roll your own VPN. Though I say “easiest”, you need quite some knowledge on networking to make port forwarding work this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your screenshot which IP is associated with your WAN and which is your internal LAN. You would want to enter the static IP address of your LAN/WLAN device to port forward. This tells your edge (VPN) device where to send traffic (internally) when it receives incoming traffic addressed to that port.

So, if the screenshot is from your internal endpoint device, then you would port forward the 192... address. If the screenshot is from your VPN device, then you would port forward the 10... address. This is because only one of the addresses has a gateway, which is the next hop out to the big web.

Based on subnetting, I would generally assume that your ISP has a 10... address space, and your internal network a 192... address space. So that makes me think you should port forward the `192.168.8.1` address.

Remember, DHCP can throw a wrench in your whole port forwarding scheme. Be sure to statically assign an IP to this device.

Comment: the 10.x address space is RFC 1918 - so its a "lan". I think that's the VPN. The other one's local and connected over wireless. You wouldn't see your IP's address space on the client behind a router doing NAT